# what will happen in this promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I created a function which returns promise which when resolves-overwrites after 2 seconds a = value of promise p which resolves  after 2 seconds

```
var a = 0;
var p = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(3);
    }, 2000);
})
function promise () {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        resolve(
            p.then(val => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    a = val;
                }, 2000);
            })

        )
    })
}
```

Following code outputs value of after promise returned by above function has resolved

```
promise().then( () => {
    console.log(a);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
})
```

Comment: So did you run it and find out?

Comment: Very weird you are using promises, but use a global variable.

Comment: I ran it.I used global variable to know if promise p has resolved.if it has resolved shouldn't a be 3;

Comment: Your variable is not changed at the moment the promise resolved, but 2 seconds later. So don't expect the variable to be a good indicator of when the promise resolved.

Comment: shouldn't that promise resolve only after all the code inside resolve() block has run i.e. after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `setTimeout`, the promise won't wait for it, instead it will resolve immeadiately. To wait for `setTimeout` being done, create a Promise and resolve that, when the timer is finished:

```
 function promise () {
   return p.then((val) => {
     return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
                a = val;
                resolve();
       }, 2000);
     });        
   });
 }
```

But you seriously should

1) not use global variables, especially with async stuff

2) not wrap each setTimeout manually in a promise, instead write a helper once:

```
  const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

Then your code could be written as:

```
 delay(2000)
   .then(() => 2)
   .then(a => delay(2000).then(() => a))
   .then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not super sure what your question is, but I think there's a bunch of weird stuff going on.

First this snippet:

```
var p = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(3);
}, 2000);
});
```

I think your intent here is to create some functionality that simply creates a promise that resolves after 2 seconds. The problem is, you only create 1 promise. After you call that snippet the clock immediately starts running and any future use of this same promise immediately resolves. Instead, I think you want to create a function that creates a fresh version of this promise every time:

```
const wait2s = () => {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(res, 2000);
  });
};
```

Next, you want to create a function that changes the contents of a variable after 2 seconds. This is my version of that:

```
const myDelayedOperation = () => {
   return wait2s.then(() => {
     a = 3;
   });
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i am trying to figure out working of promises by this code.

Comment: shouldn't a = 3 once promise is resolved

Comment: I felt that that belonged to the second snippet, not the first.